# Assign string to pointer in struct - Linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list, c-strings

I'm trying to write a program for students linked list in C.
Here is the struct:

```
typedef struct student *studp;
typedef struct student{
    int number;
    char *name;
    char *date;
    unsigned grade;
    studp next;
}stud;
```

Now I want to write a function which creates new node and assign values to members.
I'm not sure how to do it, here is the function:

```
studp create_stud(int number, char *name, char *date, unsigned grade){
studp item = (studp)malloc(sizeof(stud));
if(!item){
    printf("Cannot allocate memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
item->number = number;
item->name = .....


return item;
```

}
how should I assign the text to the member name and date? can I use the operator '=':

```
item->name = name;
```

or I should allocate the memory with malloc() ?
and if I use malloc() should I free the pointer in the and of the program or I just can release the node?
Thanks!

Comment: Hiding pointers under typedef is evil.

Comment: What do you mean>

Comment: And calling `studp` that looks confusingly like `strdup()` was going to make me crazy.

Comment: @ToharPingley That you should never do `typedef POINTER_TYPE *NON_POINTER_TYPE` because it's confusing.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Got it.

Answer (score 2):

```
item->name = strdup(name);
```

This will do the trick. In case you don't have this (`strdup` is a POSIX thing) allocate memory and then use `strcpy`/`memcpy` to copy the string pointed by `name`.

Don't hide pointers inside `typedef` it's easier to maintain in large codebase - you always have to look back to get what it's type is to write correct code.

Don't cast the return value of `malloc` and check the return value of `strdup` just like you did for `malloc`. Also `free` the memory allocated using `malloc` and `strdup` when you are done working with it.

To show you an example. (Illustration)

```
stud* item = malloc(sizeof *item);
if(NULL == item){
    perror("Cannot allocate memory\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
...

free(item->name);
free(item->date);
/* whatever you have allocated */
free(item);
```

---

Edit: In case `strdup` is not there.

```
item->name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
if(!item->name){
   perror("malloc");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
memcpy(item->name, name, strlen(name)+1);
```

Comment: @ToharPingley Yes you should, just like `malloc()` `strdup()` does return `NULL` on failure. You should also `free()` the pointer, the pointer returned by `strdup()` is one returned internally by `malloc()` so all the same rules apply. And if you mean that you're afraid to pass a `NULL` pointer, well yes check, it's UB to pass `NULL` to `strdup()`.

Comment: @ToharPingley.: That depends - if you need to validate input here then you must but in case you call this function with already validated input then you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks! and if I write a function to free the list should I add : "free(name)"?

Comment: @ToharPingley Yes, note that it would be `free(studp_instance->name)`, but yes, that's what the comment tries to say. The answer now includes it too.

Comment: If I use strcpy() won't it be a security issue?

Comment: @ToharPingley.: Well if you are cmpeting in between `strncpy` vs `strcpy` I would just say that when you are copying make sure target has enough space. That will be good enough.

Comment: Oops, I've got a problem. I don't think that strdup() is in ANSIC.

Comment: @ToharPingley.:Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[What do I do when someone answers my
question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Your structure contains `char*` members.  They can point to a string, but they can't *contain* a string.  In order to copy over those string members, you need to allocate buffers for the `char*` fields in the new structure, then `strncpy()` over the contents.

It's your responsibility to free *all* memory that you allocate.  Think of it as if every `malloc` call needs a matching `free`.  I recommend writing a corresponding `delete_stud` function that handles cleanup.  It can free the memory associated with the structure, plus any buffers allocated for the `char*` members.